# How to integrate citrus payment gateway in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, payment-gateway, citrus-pay

I am trying to integrate citrus payment gateway to my application which is written in zend. I am using citrus hostel checkout. I am generating signature in controller and then pass these values to view where a form is created. 
Controller code:

```
$formPostUrl = "https://sandbox.citruspay.com/sslperf/your-vanityUrlPart";  
$secret_key = "xxxxxx"; // your secret key
$vanityUrl = "xxx"; // your vanity url
$merchantTxnId = uniqid(); 
$orderAmount = "1.00";
$currency = "INR";
$TransactionData= $vanityUrl.$orderAmount.$merchantTxnId.$currency;
$securitySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $TransactionData, $secret_key); 
$data = [
    'formPostUrl' => $formPostUrl,
    'vanityUrl' => $vanityUrl,
    'merchantTxnId' => $merchantTxnId,
    'orderAmount' => $orderAmount,
    'currency' => $currency,
    'securitySignature' => $securitySignature,
    'returnUrl' => $this->hostName.'/'.'paymentResponse' 
]; 
return new ViewModel ( $data );
```

View Code:

```
<form align="center" method="post" action="<?php echo $formPostUrl;?>">
    <input ng-model="amount" type="number"class="form-control" id="orderAmount" name="orderAmount" placeholder="Enter the amount here.." required min="1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="merchantTxnId" name="merchantTxnId" value="<?php echo $merchantTxnId;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency" value="<?php echo $currency;?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="<?php echo $returnUrl;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="secSignature"  name="secSignature" value="<?php echo $securitySignature;?>" />
    <input type="Submit" value="Pay Now"/>
</form>
```

But the problem here is that securitySignature is created using amount and that code is written in controller but I have to take amount from user like a form which should be in view. I can't create securitySignature in view because it requires security_key which I can't write in view for security reasons. Is there any way from view I could send amount to controller and then in controller make a POST request to formPostUrl which also redirect me to formPostUrl just like in form we make a post request which also redirect to that url.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the steps below,

1. Create an intermediate submit handler on your controller
2. Gather the UI params there and add your server side/hidden params on that.
3. Point your UI form to the new intermediate submit handler
4. Link the call to the payment gateway using curl from there (Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676572/1304559).

P.S: You may need to store the state of the second request in logs or db or something just in case, for audit.

Hope it helps!